# What is the correct usage of cordova-plugin-app-version

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

Trying this plugin from git hub here: [cordova-plugin-app-version](https://github.com/whiteoctober/cordova-plugin-app-version)
installed ok via Cordova Cli and used example usage as given by developr on his git hub page - since im not using a 'promise' based language then he suggests this syntax:

```
cordova.getAppVersion.getVersionNumber(function (version) {
alert(version);
```

});

Not getting anything, no errors or output. Has anyone else had any luck with this plugin??

I have: Cordova version: 6.1.1 - Using with phoneGap desktop but intstalled via the cordova cli to the plugins directory ok. Added the correct line in config.xml thus : `<plugin name="cordova-plugin-app-version" version="0.1.8"/>`

Thanks ...

Comment: correct usage are already mentioned on GitHub, and check whether above code is being called or not?

Comment: Please put the given function in the 'onDeviceReady' event of the cordova, the above code in the question `cordova.getAppVersion.getVersionNumber(function (version) {
    alert(version);
});`  is working proper for me when i put this code in 'onDeviceReady'

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have the version number specified in your mobile project. In the `config.xml`. See examples [here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/config_ref/index.html#widget). Verify in your `config.xml` you have `version`, `android-versionCode`, or `ios-CFBundleVersion` attributes on the global `widget` node.

Also make sure you're making all your calls within `onDeviceReady`.

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady(){
    cordova.getAppVersion.getVersionNumber(function (version) {

    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have tried out in device running on Android Marshamallow, Cordova 6.1.1, cordova android 5.1.1. The plugin works fine and i m able to get the app version using both jquery and non jquery based approach as mentioned in the plugin documentation. The code is as follows, .
**index.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
        <title>Version Checker</title>
    </head>
    <body>              
        Get Version(jQuery based) <input type="button" value="Version" name="version" id="version"/><br>
        Get Version <input type="button" value="Version" name="version" id="version1"/><br>     
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
});

function onDeviceReady() {  
    $('#version').click (function() {
        cordova.getAppVersion.getVersionNumber().then(function (version) {
            alert('verion(jQuery based)' + version);
        });
    });

    $('#version1').click (function() {
        cordova.getAppVersion.getVersionNumber(function (version) {
            alert("version - " + version);
        });
    });
}
```